# How to implement custom listeners in cucumber?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

How to implement customer listeners in cucumber?

which can log to the console/report about the occurrence of the failed method?

*using cucumber 4.0*

Note: Hooks  are not helping at method levels

Comment: what is "the occurrence of the failed method" and why do you need to log this? Give us a sample scenario and what you need to log.

Answer (score 1):

No custom listener option in cucumber like TestNG. we should have use only Hooks.

Comment: Then how to achieve this? because using TestNG listeners are not giving the expected method name

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the ConcurrentEventListener to get certain hooks for events [[example]](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/bb8f6bb1e007870b79d8d43d828be6490b6d3189/core/src/test/java/io/cucumber/core/runner/StepDurationTimeService.java).

Events can be found [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/plugin/src/main/java/io/cucumber/plugin/event)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement listeners in cucumber like below

```
    import io.cucumber.plugin.EventListener;
    import io.cucumber.plugin.event.*;
    
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.TreeMap;
    import java.util.UUID;
    
    public class    ReportPlugin implements EventListener {
    
     private final Map<String, UUID> startedSteps = new TreeMap<String, UUID>();
     private final Map<String, Status> finishedCases = new TreeMap<String, Status>();
    
       @Override
        public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
            
            publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, this::handleTestStepStarted);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseFinished.class, this::handleTestCaseFinished);

        }
    
    private void handleTestStepStarted(TestStepStarted event) {
            startedSteps.put(event.getTestStep().toString(), event.getTestStep().getId());
            for (Map.Entry<String, UUID> entry : startedSteps.entrySet()) {
                    String location = entry.getKey();
                    UUID uuid = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println(location + " ###fromTestStepStarted### " + uuid);
            
             //above prints
            //io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep@5a5c128 ###fromTestStepStarted### 7f964f1c-9442-43fc-97e9-9ec6717eb47f
           // io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep@77b919a3 ###fromTestStepStarted### a5d57753-aecb-40a0-a0cf-76bef7526dd8

                }
        }
}
```

To run the above class - put the class with your step defs  or your supporting classes and then in `junit-platform.properties` (for Junit5) mention plugin like this

`cucumber.plugin =  com.test.support.ReportPlugin`

For Junit4 you might have to add plugin to your runner class

When you run your tests you should see everything printed on console